# How to build a dynamic hyperlink in Google-Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

I have data that contains only one column. I simply want to create a new URL column based on this column.

```
   id     url 
  1234   https://www.xyz.ne/1234
  2984   https://www.xyz.ne/2984
  1222   https://www.xyz.ne/1222
  2341   https://www.xyz.ne/2341
  5959   https://www.xyz.ne/5959
```

But I want to add an URL to a new column like this: https://www.xyz.ne/id

How can I do this?

Comment: The HYPERLINK function?

Comment: Ok, but how to do it dynamically?

Comment: Is this in Excel or google sheets?

Comment: It is in Google sheet. @a-burge

Comment: By concatenating the id with the "base" URL  with `&`.

Comment: Put this in the first cell =ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(B14:B20&A14:A20)), or just use hyperlink(B14&A14) like BigBen points out.

Comment: I did not get what you mean. @a-burge How to combine it with the url?

Comment: Ah, now I got it with the hyperlink function. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, maybe the following will do it dynamically for your whole range, no need to enter specific ranges. So type in `B2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("https://www.xyz.ne/"&FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")))
```